# Calculating alligator indicator for highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, moving-average

I have calculated the Simple Moving average and Smoothed moving average for the time period. But if the alligator has calculated SMMA (MEDEAN PRICE, period, shift) how do I add shift for smoothed moving average?

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="form-inline">
            <div class="">
              <h5> Jaws </h5>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin cls-setng-menu">
                <p> Period </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control modal_vin txtbox1" id="jaws_period" name="jaws_period" value="13">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin cls-setng-menu">
                <p> Shift </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control modal_vin txtbox1" id="jaws_shift" name="jaws_shift" value="8">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin">
                <p> Color </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-select vin-chn-bns" style="background-color: #e74c3c !important" id="jaws_a_color">
                  <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                  <span class="btn-select-value" style="background-color: #e74c3c !important;padding: 0px !important" id="jaws_color"></span><span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-vin-color" style="position:absolute;top:134%">
                    <li class="selected" style="background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_jaws_color('f1c40f')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_jaws_color('e67e22')"></li>         
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_jaws_color('e74c3c')"></li>            
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(211, 84, 0) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_jaws_color('d35400')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_jaws_color('2980b9')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(155, 89, 182) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_jaws_color('9b59b6')"></li> 
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin">
                <p> Width </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-select vin-chn-bns">
                  <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                  <span class="btn-select-value" id="jaws_width">1px</span> <span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-vin-color" style="position:absolute;top:134%">
                    <li class="selected">1px</li>
                    <li>2px</li>          
                    <li>3px</li>          
                    <li>4px</li>
                    <li>5px</li> 
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <h5> Teeth </h5>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin cls-setng-menu">
                <p> Period </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control modal_vin txtbox1" id="teeth_period" name="teeth_period" value="8">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin cls-setng-menu">
                <p> Shift </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control modal_vin txtbox1" id="teeth_shift" name="teeth_shift" value="5">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin">
                <p> Color </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-select vin-chn-bns" style="background-color: #2980b9 !important" id="teeth_a_color">
                  <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                  <span class="btn-select-value" style="background-color: #2980b9 !important;padding: 0px !important" id="teeth_color"></span><span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-vin-color" style="position:absolute;top:134%">
                    <li class="selected" style="background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_teeth_color('f1c40f')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_teeth_color('e67e22')"></li>         
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_teeth_color('e74c3c')"></li>            
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(211, 84, 0) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_teeth_color('d35400')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_teeth_color('2980b9')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(155, 89, 182) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_teeth_color('9b59b6')"></li> 
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin">
                <p> Width </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-select vin-chn-bns">
                  <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                  <span class="btn-select-value" id="teeth_width">1px</span> <span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-vin-color" style="position:absolute;top:134%">
                    <li class="selected">1px</li>
                    <li>2px</li>          
                    <li>3px</li>          
                    <li>4px</li>
                    <li>5px</li> 
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <h5> Lips </h5>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin cls-setng-menu">
                <p> Period </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control modal_vin txtbox1" id="lips_period" name="lips_period" value="5">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin cls-setng-menu">
                <p> Shift </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control modal_vin txtbox1" id="lips_shift" name="lips_shift" value="3">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin">
                <p> Color </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-select vin-chn-bns" style="background-color: #9b59b6 !important" id="lips_a_color">
                  <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                  <span class="btn-select-value" style="background-color: #9b59b6 !important;padding: 0px !important" id="lips_color"></span><span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-vin-color" style="position:absolute;top:134%">
                    <li class="selected" style="background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_lips_color('f1c40f')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_lips_color('e67e22')"></li>         
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_lips_color('e74c3c')"></li>            
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(211, 84, 0) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_lips_color('d35400')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_lips_color('2980b9')"></li>
                    <li style="background-color: rgb(155, 89, 182) ! important;padding:15px;" onclick="change_lips_color('9b59b6')"></li> 
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group modal_vin">
                <p> Width </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-select vin-chn-bns">
                  <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
                  <span class="btn-select-value" id="lips_width">1px</span> <span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-vin-color" style="position:absolute;top:134%">
                    <li class="selected">1px</li>
                    <li>2px</li>          
                    <li>3px</li>          
                    <li>4px</li>
                    <li>5px</li> 
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vin_footer text-center">
              <button onclick="alligator()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn_footer" type="submit">Apply</button>
              <button ng-click="onReset()" class="btn btn-gray btn2_footer">Reset</button>
              <button ng-click="onCancel()" class="btn btn-gray btn2_footer">Cancel</button>
            </div>
```

And uptill now I have tried for smoothed moving average using only period and not using shift values.

**Javascript code**

```
var chart = $("#tv_chart_container").highcharts();
  var series = chart.series[0];
  var jaws_data = [];
  var sumForAverage = 0;
  var EMA_previous_day = 0;
  var SMMA = 0;
  var price = 0;
  var high,low;
  var PREVSUM;
  var jaws_mul = (2 / (jaws_period + 1) );
  var teeth_mul = (2 / (teeth_period + 1) );
  var lips_mul = (2 / (lips_mul + 1) );
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<series.data.length;i++) {
    sumForAverage += series.data[i].y;
    if(i<period) {
        jaws_data.push(null);
    }
    else {
      sumForAverage -= series.data[i-period].y;
      if(SMMA == 0)
      {
        SMMA = sumForAverage/period;
      }
      else
      {
        high = chart.yAxis[0].dataMax;
        low = chart.yAxis[0].dataMin;
        price = (high + low)/2;
        PREVSUM = SMMA *period;
        SMMA = (PREVSUM-SMMA+price)/period;
      }
      jaws_data.push([series.data[i].x, SMMA]);
    }
  }
  chart.addSeries({
      name: 'Jaws',
      linkedTo: 'primary',
      showInLegend: true,
      type: 'trendline',
      algorithm: 'SMA',
      periods: jaws_period,
      lineWidth:jaws_width,
      lineColor:jaws_color,
      data:jaws_data
  });
```

I would like to know how I can use shift values to smoothed moving average?